# Filter Azure function logs using NLog

Tags: azure, azure-functions, nlog

I'm trying to set up NLog to work with my Azure durable function (v4).

The NLog does configuration progromatically (not using config file) and writes to an Azure DB target via a sp.

It is working well in general. But there are lots of undesired logs both of debug and info level showing up in the DB along with my own user logs. They are the output of Azure service loggers like `Azure.Core.1`, `DurableTask.AzureStorage`, `Host.xxx`.

I tried several ways to filter them out:

- adding items like `"Azure.Core.1" : "Error"` to the host.json file.
- adding log filter like `logBuilder.AddFilter("Azure.Core.1", Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Error)`
- adding NLog rule like `config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("Azure.Core.1", NLog.LogLevel.Error, target));`

But none of them works... Any advice, please?

Comment: You can use `WriteToNil` to suppress logger-output. See also  https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#fluent-api-for-nlog-loggingconfiguration

Comment: Hi @RolfKristensen thanks for the advice. I did give the new fluent API a try by adding `c.ForLogger("Azure.*").WriteToNil(LogLevel.Warn)` but still it's not working. The `Azure.Core.1` logs just won't go away... I think the fluent API is just a wrapper for the logging rule.

Comment: Remember the order of adding the LoggingRules is important. The logging-rules that actually writes to targets, should be added last (Just like in the example from the link provided). You have not provided any details on how you build your NLog-config, so I cannot guide you that much.

Comment: @RolfKristensen That's it! The existing code sets the rules in the configuration instead of using the fluent API. My previous change was mixing the two approaches. I have tried consolidating them all into one place in the correct order, now it's finally working. Thanks a heap! Do you mind elaborate the solution into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog evaluates the [LoggingRules](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules) from top to bottom. This means global filters should be added first, and having the actual targets at the very end.

```cs
var myTarget = new AmazingNLogTarget();

var logger = LogManager.Setup().LoadConfiguration(c =>
{
   c.ForLogger("System.*").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Warn);
   c.ForLogger("Microsoft.*").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Warn);
   c.ForLogger("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime*").WriteToNil(NLog.LogLevel.Info);   // finalMinLevel overrides previous rule

   c.ForLogger().FilterMinLevel(NLog.LogLevel.Info).WriteTo(myTarget);
}).GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

See also: https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#fluent-api-for-nlog-loggingconfiguration